# Azure DevOps fails with error /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.105/NuGet.targets(499,5): error : Could not find a part of the path '/tmp/NuGetScratch

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline

I am Developing an `Azure Function` solution where I have 2 `class library` and one Azure Function projects. I have already setup the `Azure DevOps` build and release pipelines. With my recent changes I am getting an error as `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.105/NuGet.targets(499,5): error : Could not find a part of the path '/tmp/NuGetScratch` whenever the `azure build pipeline` is running.

[image]

I am not sure what made this problem. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: For someone who may stumble upon this issue on hosted Ubuntu agent 1604 - I had to build the .csproj instead of .sln file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that the issue is with the project target framework. All my projects in the solution are in `.Net Core 2.1` except one project (`class library`) was in `.Net Standard`. This was a mistake I had done while creating the class library project, I selected class library (.NET Standard) instead of selecting `Class Library (.NET Core)`.

[image]

I removed that project (both from visual studio and file explorer) and create a new project with the same name but this time by selecting `Class Library (.NET Core)` and then copied my classes to this project.

[image]

That fixed my issue. Hope it helps.